# Windows 10 screensaver often stops working/doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, display-settings

Not sure when, why, or how but every day to couple of days while having my PC on (it doesn't sleep), the screensaver suddenly stops coming on and instead the screen stays on and also never sleeps. I've been jokingly considering it some insomniac reflex but I digress. Rebooting the system restores functionality.

So far as I can tell I am not running anything that wouldn't be running when it does work. There's no videos or audio playing or even open somewhere. `powercfg.exe /waketimers` says there's nothing.

I also have another system running Win10 where the screensaver just flat out never works. Never worked on Win8.1 and still doesn't after the upgrade.

I am using the photos screensaver on PC1 and ribbons on PC2. Both work when I test them manually.

How can I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: possibly sfc /scannow in cmd or it could be a driver problem?

Comment: I've done sfc /scannow several times. Definitely a goto for weird system issues but I'm not sure it's ever helped. I suppose it could be a driver issue. I've gone through every device in the device manager and disabled the power management (can prevent sleep) option where applicable. Maybe reinstalling GPU drivers?

Comment: I would give it a shot.  It's and odd issue