# Screensaver simply doesn't work in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

The problem maybe similar to

[Windows 10 screensaver often stops working/doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/1044495/windows-10-screensaver-often-stops-working-doesnt-work)

The difference is, since I reinstall windows 10 in this computer, it never works. That one seems to use to work but not working anymore.

Basically I like security. I do not want people to be able to access my file at all.

Sometimes I forget to log out and just leave my computer.

When I come back, my computer is still open.

I want to make sure that my computer is logged out or at least switched out or whatever the term is for windows 10 after 1-2 minutes.

I believe I set things up very correctly

[image]

There I set that up. Bubbles screen saver. Log out after 2 minutes.

Yet that screensaver never shows up.

What did I do wrong?

Is there another screen saver setting somewhere else that override this?

Comment: `Settings > Power & sleep > Screen > When plugged in, turn off after > XX minutes` is a good place to look. The screensaver is pretty much obsolete these days as actually turning off the display is far more power efficient.

Comment: Some programs prevent screensavers and sleep, for example video play. The problem might be because of some running program.

Comment: I want people need to login before being able to access my computer. I mainly want security,.